# htaccess rewriterule and redirect not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I have a particular scenario: the old site urls were made this way: `http://www.mysite.it/it/my-old-link`

The new one are made this way: `http://www.mysite.it/vini.php?famiglia=my-new-link`

I would like to the link `http://www.mysite.it/it/my-old-link` to point to `http://www.mysite.it/vini.php?famiglia=my-new-link`

This is to preserve SEO position. So, when someone click on search result `http://www.mysite.it/it/my-old-link will be redirected` to `http://www.mysite.it/vini.php?famiglia=my-new-link`

But I cannot find a way to do this editing the .htaccess file.

I've set a rewrite rule and a redirect but it doesn't work; here an example of the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^/?([^/d]+)/?$ /vini.php?famiglia=$1 [L,QSA]

Redirect 302 http://www.mysite.it/it/my-old-link http://www.mysite.it/my-new-link

ErrorDocument 404 http://www.mysite.it/index.php
```

But it doesn't work: if I enter `http://www.mysite.it/it/my-old-link` in the browser I get the 404 page error (index.php)

However: if I enter `http://www.mysite.it/my-new-link` on the browser I get the correct page.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

TIA tony

Answer (score 1):

In case you are looking for specific rule as per shown samples then try following.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^it/my-old-link/?$ vini.php?famiglia=my-new-link [NC,L]
```

---

---

In case you are looking for Generic rules, where if a URI is NOT present as a file or directory then try following. Please make sure either you put above or following rules only at a time.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ vini.php?famiglia=my-new-link [NC,L]
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. The problem, here , is that the old files are not real file, so I cannot use the first code. If I use it I get error 404. I tried the second code but it change all links to the one I specify. Is there a way to make it specific for every couple (old-file-link/new-file-link)?. 
I tried this code, but I get error 404:
```RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/it/old-file-link\.html/$ vini.php?famiglia=new-file-link  [NC,L]```